# Moving an Excel Worksheet to Access with VBA error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hello I am trying to move an Excel worksheet to an Access database, both of which have identical field names. The Code is written in Excel.

The user inputs several form fields and upon clicking finish, a seperate worksheet is updated. Then, the update Access subroutine is called to update the database with the contents of the sheet. However I continue to receive the following error:

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

I googled the error and can't quite see what is going on. Here is my code:

```
Sub Update_Access_fromExcel()
```

' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long

' Connect to Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & "Data Source=D:\Tool_Database\Tool_Database.mdb;"

' open the recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "Project_Names", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
r = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("NewProj").Cells(r, 1))
    With rs
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Proj_Name") = Worksheets("NewProj").Cells(r, 1).Value
        .Update
    End With
    r = r + 1
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

Also, is there a way I could just add the new info to the end of the Access database?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are working from the Access end, why are you not just linking the Excel sheet and running a query using the query design window?

Comment: @Remou, Do you know where I could find information on how to do that? Sounds like that is the easiest way.

Comment: @HansUp I am very new to VBA and I don't know how to debug to figure out the line #... :(

Comment: Here : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-export-and-link-data-between-access-and-excel-HP001095095.aspx It is all driven by wizards.

Comment: On the message dialog which displays the error notice, click the Debug button.  Your code will open in the VB editor with the problem line highlighted.

Comment: Can the database be truly linked to the Excel worksheet? For example, if a user enters a new item in the worksheet, can access automatically update to reflect the change?

Comment: If the data in the Excel file is organized as a table, it will link well. You can even link ranges and yes, updates will show in Access in the linked table. However, if you want to copy the data across to a local Access table, you will need to run a query.